# Dynamic php modal

Tags: php, for-loop, dynamic, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying create modal that is dynamic and pre fills with the details of the item that is clicked on. Here is my code:

HTML:

---

```
{foreach from=$flowers3 item=row}

{foreach from=$row item=item}

  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <div class="quickview">

          <a alt="Quick View" class="btn btn-xs  btn-quickview" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal"> View </a>
        </div>

        <a href="#">
          <img class="item_thumb img-responsive" src="img/{$item.im}" alt="img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="item_name">{$item.title}</h4>

        <p class="item_price">
          small&nbsp;
          <input type="Radio" name="product" value="{$item.id}s" style="border:0;cursor:pointer;" />
          <span style="font-weight: bold">${$item.ps|money:0}</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp; med&nbsp;

          <input type="Radio" name="product" value="{$item.id}m" style="border:0;cursor:pointer;" />
          <span style="font-weight: bold">${$item.pm|money:0}</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp; lg&nbsp;

          <input type="Radio" name="product" value="{$item.id}l" style="border:0;cursor:pointer;" />
          <span style="font-weight: bold">${$item.pl|money:0}</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="action-control">
        <a href="javascript:;" onClick="mySubmit()">
          <span class="button-fill grey">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">
                </i> Add to cart </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS['flowers']=getFlowers();

function &getFlowers(){
    static $flowers;
    if(!isset($flowers)){
        $flowers=array(
'1'=>array('im'=>'store-a1.jpg','title'=>'CocoChanel','description'=>' Fashion fades.'),
'2'=>array('im'=>'store-a2.jpg','title'=>'The Royal Jewels','description'=>'Fit for any Queen.'),);}

$i=1;
foreach($flowers as $k=>&$v){
    $v['id']=$k;
    $v['num']=$i++;}
return $flowers;}
?>
```

And here's the modal:

```
            <!--modal -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"> ×</button>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5  col-xs-12">
                        <!-- product Image -->
                        <div class="main-image  col-lg-12 no-padding style3 modal-image">
                            <a class="product-largeimg-link" href="#">
                                <img src="img/{$item.imb}" class="img-responsive product-largeimg" alt="img">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!--/image-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/ product Image-->
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 modal-details no-padding">
                    <div class="modal-details-inner">
                        <h1 class="product-title">{$item.title}</h1>

                        <div class="details-description">
                            <p>{$item.description}</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--/modal -->
```

When I add the modal within the {foreach} tags, it only fills with the information for one particular item (depending on where I place it. ex: it might be the first item, or if I place it between the {foreach from=$flowers3 item=row} it will be the last of the first row) but I can't get it to update every item on the particular "Quick View" that is clicked.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Store the properties of the items in data-attributes of the item 's in your html:

```
<div class="item ..." ... data-title="Nice flower" data-price="€1,20" > ... </div>
```

Now use some javascript to update the modal. jQuery example:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
var el = $(this);
$('.modal .product-title').text(el.attr('data-title'));
// and the rest of the properties, then open the modal
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But since the html is being loaded dynamically, if I try to add <div class="item ..." ... data-title="{$item.title}"> it won't work.

Comment: What framework are you using? I see that you are iterating over flowers3 and over row. Does flowers3 contain three flowers? If so, this step is unneccessary since bootstrap will ensure that your flowers will show up three at a row because you used the bootstrap grid.

Comment: Thank you I fixed this and it's much cleaner now. Thanks!